# Creating a Developer VM in Azure

Tags: azure, visual-studio, docker

I am looking to do some learning on docker and Azure. My own PC isn't high enough spec to do this. I don't want to use my work PC.

Is it possible to create a development VM in Azure and put Visual Studio and Docker on it?

I want to use VS to create Docker images of applications, use Docker manage them and connect to Azure through VS. If I try to do this on an Azure VM will it cause problems?

Anyone spot any issues rather than buy a new PC? I just think a new PC will be too much.

Comment: Buying a couple of RAM sticks is usually way cheaper than provisioning an Azure VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have an Azure VM with VS and Docker installed, and it works fine. In fact you can get VMs with Visual Studio preinstalled so you only need to install Docker.

My VM costs about a dollar an hour (while it's running), plus a little overhead for storage, that counts against my MSDN credits.